# Can you revive the creature you sacrificed with Hell's Caretaker?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can you revive the creature you sacrificed with [Hell's Caretaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=84590)?

Doing so to re-trigger "enters the battlefield" effects.

Comment: If you have more than 1 other creature, you can swap them in and out of the GY, though. You can even go infinite using 2x Deceiver Exarch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No

The steps to casting a spell or activating an ability are:

1. 601.2a) Place card or ability on stack.
2. 601.2b-d) Make choices, including targets.
3. 601.2e) Determine total cost.
4. 601.2f) Activate mana abilities.
5. 601.2g) Pay the previously determined cost.

The sacrificed creature is only moved to the graveyard in step 5, but you need to pick a card in the graveyard in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You have to choose a creature to 'target' at the time you activate the ability (Rule 601.2c). At this point in the activating process, you have not payed the cost to active the ability(rule 601.2g), so the creature you would sacrifice is not in the graveyard and is not a valid target.

Answer (score -5):

Yes. THis is possible. You can also use cards in your hand

Comment: Add more thorough documentation, correct grammar, punctuation, etc.